# Quarrelsome Quilen Quintet?

Tags: achievements, world-of-warcraft

What is the location of all of the Jade Quilen in the Mogu'Shan instance for the Quarrelsome Quilen Quintet achievement?

[image]

> **Quarrelsome Quilen Quintet**
>
> Collect all the Jade Quilen located throughout Mogu'Shan Palace on Heroic difficulty.

Are these always in the same locations or are the locations randomly generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing this achievement involves looking around the instance and looting various Jade Quilen, usually located behind trash or in hard to reach places, in a similar manner to the Extra Credit Bonus Stage achievement from Vortex Pinnacle during Cataclysm.

The locations of the Quilen you need to loot are;

- hidden at the very end of the first room, behind the trash
- next to Kual the Brute in the first boss room
- hidden in an alcove on right, after going down the hidden steps from the first boss but before the first Glimtrok Scout
- around to the left or right side of the balcony before Gekkan
- in either of the two rooms immediately before the last boss, click the Orb to break down the Jade Statue and it should be there

In addition, if you have a hunter in the group, there is a Jade Quilen which spawns inside one of the vaults, which can be tracked. This vault can be opened without needing an Ancient Mogu Key.

Answer (score 0):

As per [comments on WoWHead](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=6713), a poster says these all spawn in specific locations.